# customer/account and customer/address assistance. magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, javascript

I have scoured the git repository and my local copy, I am trying to find what files magento2 uses to create the edit section of the customer account dashboard for address. specifically for logged in customers when they click the edit address link. I need to remove first and last name from those screens and add company on them. I found it for the customer checkout section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify the edit address for you will need to copy the following file to your theme

Copy from

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml
```

To

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/address/edit.phtml
```

Once you have copied the file across to your theme you should be able to edit the template and implement your changes.

to remove the name fields you remove the following line

```
 <?= $block->getNameBlockHtml() ?>
```

As for company you should be able to enable company name in the admin user

```
Store > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configuration > Show Company
```

If you want to implement these on the dashboard you may need to copy grid.phtml and book.phtml from the same location as above

Comment: Slightly off in my case, in composer its /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml.